# Fix alignment of sliding doors

Tags: doors

I have a double sliding door with a lock, that only works if I lift one side by about 1-2mm. This requieres a lot of force, since this is a solid wood door. The doors do not seem to be parallel to each other. Illustration:

[image: sliding door illustration]

The doors appears to be mounted in a way that makes adjustments rather hard. Do I have to unscrew the castors from the door and then remove them to try to adjust the distance? The doors are completely inside the door frame.

[image][image]

Edit: After the suggestion I tried to move/remove the stop element. It is loose after unscrewing it, but can't be moved or removed.

[image: stop element]

Comment: Barn door or overhead trolley rails usually are harder to adjust. If there is no lower rail and you cannot access the hardware with out removal that is probably your only path forward.

Answer (score 1):

There's usually a removable stop or jamb component that would allow you to lift the doors off the track. You may also need to remove a channel or rod to allow the doors to be swung outward at the bottom.

Then you'd make adjustments to the bracket length using the screws you can see there. Modern hardware has more convenient means of adjustment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it, but for some reason I can't remove the stop. Any suggestion? (I added an image to the question)

Comment: By "stop" I'm referring to the painted wood strips attached to the jamb. Do any of them have screws rather than nails as their attachment mechanism?

Comment: As far as I can see there are only nails

Comment: often, all that is necessary is to lift the door up enough for the wheel to clear the side of the rail then move it over and it will drop right out. Based on your pictures, I think there is enough room. You might have to remove something from the bottom of the door first, if there is a rail or guide on the door or floor. Then swing the bottom of the door out a bit while lowering down. It's a bit tricky and takes some practice but it works. Then adjust as noted